# How to retrieve Hashtable from mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, hashtable

I am storing hashtable in mongodb using BasicDBObject.
And now I want to retrieve this hashtable.How can I do this?

```
HashTable<String, Login> loginHashTable;
HashTable<String, Other> otherHashTable;

DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(users);
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.insert("HashTable1", loginHashTable);
obj.insert("HashTable2", otherHashTable);
coll.insert(obj);
```

It is stored properly without errors but how can I retrieve a particulat hashTable. Suppose I want to retrieve loginHashTable. So, how can I do this?

```
Somewhat like this:
HashTable <String,Login> retrieveTable = obj.get("HashTable1");
```

My login class is like this:

```
public class Login extends ReflectionDBObject implements Serializable
{
    /** Enterprise user name used for authentication. */
    public String username = null;

    /** Enterprise password used for authentication. */
    public String password = null;

    /**Name of manufacturer of mobile phone*/
    public String manufacturer = null;

    /**Name of model of mobile phone*/
    public String model = null;

    /**Language in which Mobile software release is needed*/
    public String language = null;

    /**Current version of the software*/
    public String version = null;

    public static String id;
}
```

My other class is like this:

```
public class Other extends ReflectionDBObject implements Serializable
{
   public String sessionID = null;
}
```

Comment: is the problem the fact that you want to maintain type parameters?

Comment: No, I just want to get back that loginHashTable back later at any moment after storing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds HashTable as a BasicDBObject(HashMap format) into the DB. So, in order to retrieve data you should first get HashTable as a HashMap and then convert it manually to HashTable.Here is the example shows how you can retrieve data as HashTable format.I tried it with the `HashTable<String,String>`.

In order to insert Login class into the Mongo, you can use object mapping library such as [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) . Second way you can use [ReflectionDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/ReflectionDBObject.html) . If you extend ReflectionDBObject you can add Login object.

Login class :

```
public class Login extends ReflectionDBObject {

    /** Enterprise user name used for authentication. */
    private String username;

    /** Enterprise password used for authentication. */
    private String password;

    /**Name of manufacturer of mobile phone*/
    private String manufacturer;

    /**Name of model of mobile phone*/
    private String model;

    /**Language in which Mobile software release is needed*/
    private String language;

    /**Current version of the software*/
    private String version;

    private String id;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Other class :

```
public class Other extends ReflectionDBObject{
    public String sessionID;

    // Getter & Setter
}
```

Insert & Find methods

```
public void insert() {
    Login login = new Login();
    login.setUsername("test");
    login.setPassword("12345");
    login.setLanguage("english");

    Other other = new Other();
    other.setSessionID("111111");

    Hashtable<String, Login> loginHashTable = new Hashtable<String, Login>();
    loginHashTable.put("login", login);

    Hashtable<String, Other> otherHashTable = new Hashtable<String, Other>();
    otherHashTable.put("other", other);

    DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
    obj.put("HashTable1", loginHashTable);
    obj.put("HashTable2", otherHashTable);
    coll.insert(obj);
}

public void find() {
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    DBCursor cur = coll.find(query);

    for (DBObject obj : cur) {
        HashMap<String, Login> loginHashMap = (HashMap<String, Login>) obj.get("HashTable1");
        Hashtable<String, Login> loginHashTable = new Hashtable<String, Login>();
        loginHashTable.putAll(loginHashMap);

        HashMap<String, Other> otherHashMap = (HashMap<String, Other>) obj.get("HashTable2");
        Hashtable<String, Other> otherHashTable = new Hashtable<String, Other>();
        otherHashTable.putAll(otherHashMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class com.hss.objects.Login

Comment: I update my post. You can solve it by extending ReflectionDBObject. Login extends ReflectionDBObject {}

Comment: I extended DBObject.. Login extends DBObject but it gives me an Invocation Target Exception while inserting... Can u help me? Actually I don't want to use Morphia in that...

Comment: Try to extend ReflectionDBObject insetead of DBObject. Login extends ReflectionDBObject. It will solve your problem.

Comment: OK...can't try it ryt now.. will try on monday ans ask you again if that doesn't work..

Comment: Hey, ReflectionDBObject is also not working. Can u give me an example that how can I do this using morphia. Because on internet all what I can see is to store only one class in which u can have other classes embedded. But I don't wanna do that. I want to store diff. classes in database depending on my requirement. Example is what I gave above. Plz help.

Comment: Can you add the exact example that you tried here, so that i can understand the problem clearly.

Comment: I have edited that. You can see it now. Plz help. I need to submit project this week.

Comment: hey.. this is storing.. but in the _id attribute it stores null for all Login Objects of the HashTable. Then how I am going to get unique login objects. Can we talk in chat room?

Comment: If you want to store login with unique id then you should store it as seperate object and make the relation between login and your content.Sure, write me the name of room.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12986/discussion-between-shalki-and-parvin)